# How to calculate the Euclidean distance between vectors?

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate the Euclidean distance between each pair of num1, num2 and center1 but an error is shown: "double Conversion to double from cell is not possible"

```
 [num1]={4,4,4,4,43,4,34,55,6,6,6,65,5,4,4,43,2,2,3,45,6,67,7,7,7,7,4,5,66,5,4,3,3,2,3,4,5};
 [num2]={41,42,43,44,43,4,3,5,62,62,63,65,54,4,4,4,24,24,34,4,6,6,47,47,7,7,4,45,16,51,41,13,3,2,3,4,5};
[center1]={20,30};
```

Comment: complete of code
x=[num1(1),num2(1);center1(1),center1(2)];
pdist(x,'euclidean');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array like this:

```
a = [1 2 3 4];
```

Using curly braces like you did it creates a cell array.

To get the distance, you may use the MATLAB function `pdist`:

```
D = pdist(X)
```

This computes the Euclidean distance between pairs of objects in *m*-by-*n* data matrix *X*.

To calculate the Euclidean distance between two vectors:

```
a = [1 2 3 4];
b = [1 2 4 4];

d = pdist([a;b])
```

For further information, refer to the [documentation](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html).

Comment: x=[num1(1),num2(1);center1(1),center1(2)];
d= pdist(x,'euclidean');


what's wrong with this

Comment: just an easy thing, i get it thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

The `pdist` command requires the Statistics and Machine Learning toolbox.  If you don't have that toolbox, you can also do it with basic operations.  Euclidian distance between two vectors of points is simply the sqrt(sum( (a-b).^2 ).  So, you can do:

```
a = [1 2]; %2D vector, though any dimension is OK
b = [4 7]; %any values, but must be same size as `a`
dist = sqrt(sum((a-b).^2)); %Euclidian distance
```

No toolboxes needed!

As mentioned in the other answer, don't use curly braces to enclose your numbers.  This is a case where you need plain matlab arrays, which are the square brackets as used above.